# How to catch an exception only if another exception as not occured in C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

So I'm a student in programming and I want my code to do a try-catch on an exception but ONLY if another exception as not occured. Let me show you want I did:

```
using (var ctxInsert = new model())
{
    CATEGORIES c1 = new CATEGORIES(6, "cat6", "category6");
    Console.WriteLine("Please wait while rows are added to tables...");
    //first try-catch to know if the new entry exist
    try
    {
        ctxInsert.CATEGORIES.Add(c1);
        
    }
    catch (ModelValidationException e1)
    {
        
       Console.WriteLine(e1.Message);
       Console.WriteLine("Category already exist");
            
    }
    //second try-catch to make sure saving changes to table is succesful
    try
    {
       ctxInsert.SaveChanges();
       Console.WriteLine(c1.NAME + " : Succesfuly added");
    }
    catch (DbEntityValidationException e)
    {
       Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
       Console.WriteLine("not done");
    }    
    
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

So what I'm trying to do is that the second try-catch block only runs if the first DIDN'T catch an exception. Cause right now, like this, both try-catch runs and it doesn't make sense to save changes if the first one catches an exception.

I tried a bunch of things on my own but nothing works...

Comment: add a `return` statement in the first catch.

Comment: As @MathewHD mentioned you can use a return statement in the first catch block. Alternatively, you can have some sort of bool "flag" variable that you set to false in the catch. Then when the second try/catch goes to run you can use an if statement to block the execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need just to make your code working as you expected, you can write like this:

```
using (var ctxInsert = new model())
        {
            CATEGORIES c1 = new CATEGORIES(6, "cat6", "category6");
            Console.WriteLine("Please wait while rows are added to tables...");
            //first try-catch to know if the new entry exist
            try
            {
                ctxInsert.CATEGORIES.Add(c1);
                ctxInsert.SaveChanges();
                Console.WriteLine(c1.NAME + " : Succesfuly added");
                
            }
            catch (ModelValidationException e1)
            {
                
               Console.WriteLine(e1.Message);
               Console.WriteLine("Category already exist");
                    
            }
            catch (DbEntityValidationException e)
            {
               Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
               Console.WriteLine("not done");
            }    
            
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
```

BUT, I'd rather write code without any try/catch but make exception interceptors on top level of your application (There are best practices, depending on what framework you are using)

Comment: Thanks !!! Your way works PERFECTLY !!! ... I found out later that there was some other problem with my code the (ModelValidationException) wasn't what I thought it was. So when I replaced that with (DbUpdateException) using your method it worked #1

Answer (score 1):

The whole point of a try-catch is to stop an exception from preventing the rest of your code from executing. In your case, there are a few options I see off the top of my head:

1. Decide whether a try-catch is really what you're looking for - you could also have your method throw an exception and prevent execution of the rest of the code
2. Throw an exception in your catch, that way you get your logs and it tells the rest of the code that something went wrong, preventing execution
3. Use a variable which gets modified by the first catch, then conditionally execute the rest of the code based on that variable
4. Use a try-catch-finally

Comment: Nope, that's not the entire point of catching an exception. It can sometimes allow you to restore state to where things continue to work **OR** take compensating actions **OR** log the error somewhere **OR** simply be unlucky where you need to try multiple alternatives yet the only API available throws upon failure. You may not want to continue executing in the first two cases. Or consider C++, where lexically bounded destruction automatically provides exception safety if you are careful to not throw from them, making the first two unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can use the finally keyword let me show you with code example

```
using System;

namespace ErrorHandlingApplication {
class DivNumbers {
  int result;

  DivNumbers() {
     result = 0;
  }

  public void division(int num1, int num2) {
     try {
        result = num1 / num2;
     } catch (DivideByZeroException e) {
        Console.WriteLine("Exception caught: {0}", e);
     } finally {
        Console.WriteLine("Result: {0}", result);
     }
  }

  static void Main(string[] args) {
     DivNumbers d = new DivNumbers();
     d.division(25, 0);
     Console.ReadKey();
  }
```

}
}